# Who gains money when domestic photovoltaic electricity is injected on the grid?

Tags: power-grid

As an equity measure to ensure that everyone pays for the grid use, in multiple places we, the citizens/consumers, don't get refunded when we inject our excess photovoltaic production into the grid.

Now this excess production is available on the grid and someone, for ex. a neighbor, will consume it and get billed for it.

The electricity provider of this neighbor has earned money for some electricity it hasn't produced, nor bought.

Is it correct to say that the provider earns *free money* in that case ? Or is there another mechanism that takes place ? ex: transmission losses, intervention of grid maintenance company, ...

Comment: there must be a contract and certified equipment with scope defined for when , how much and how credits or payment is made

Comment: Usually, at least around here, the electric power supplier is required to buy excess solar power produced by a private solar panel installation.  Yes it has to be metered, and rates established.  But the utility does not get the power for free.

Comment: "we, the citizens/consumers, don't get refunded" - well, don't do it then. Use it to charge a battery bank that you can use later to save buying it when it's dark and save money.

Comment: We signed a 25 year contract that pays for all power injected into the grid. One reason why we make sure to use at night... Wasting sunlight power costs us money - the night-time power is much cheaper. :)

Comment: "Who gains money?"  is an economics question.  Are you really asking what service the provider is delivering that might justify pocketing $ for kWh entering the grid from a user's solar system?

Comment: Rules and contracts differ between countries, even regions. And here, domestic batteries are still too expensive to be profitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a big national grid, with a scattering of home PV systems, the exported electricity ends up lost in the system.

The grid will always have losses, from the transformers and the very long lines.  This lost electricity gets factored into the billing rates.  Nobody gets specifically billed for it; it's just added to the cost per unit or standing charge.

All the exported PV power covers losses that the suppliers won't have to pay for any more.  So either their profits go up a bit, or the price of electricity can be dropped a bit for everybody.

Comment: Normally, who pays for the losses ? When a power plant produces 1MWh, does the producer bill 1MWh to its consumers ? Or less because of the losses ?

Comment: @ThCollignon Ultimately, the consumers will always end up paying.  The generators will meter how much they are generating.  Each consumer has a meter.  The total consumed will always be less than the total generated.  So the loss is made up by adding a bit to the wholesale price per unit.